# Abstract type X must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field X

Tags: node.js, graphql, resolver

I'm new to GraphQL, and I've run into the issue mentioned in the title. I've tried all the solutions to the problem and still cannot figure it out. I know it is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to work my problem.

I'm trying to log in a user and return whatever type of user gets logged in, its details are sent back as a response. I've made a union for all the types.

```
type User{
    email: String!
    userType: String!
    userDetails: UserDetails!
}

union UserDetails = Customer | Admin | Gardener

extend type Query{
        login(credentials: UserLoginInput!): User

}
```

My Login function is as follows:

```
export const UserQuery = {
  loginCustomer: async (_, args) => {
    const { email, password, userType } = args.credentials;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email, userType });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }
    const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      throw new Error("Incorrect password");
    }
    if (user.bannedStatus) {
      throw new Error("User is banned");
    }
    let userDetails;
    switch (userType) {
      case "customer":
        userDetails = await CustomerModel.findOne({ userID: user._id });
        break;
      case "admin":
        userDetails = await AdminModel.findOne({ userID: user._id });
        break;
      case "gardener":
        userDetails = await GardenerModel.findOne({ userID: user._id });
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("User type not found");
    }
    return {
      email: user.email,
      userType: user.userType,
      userDetails: userDetails,
    };
  },
```

I've written a resolver function too in the Resolver

```
export const UserResolvers = {
  userDetails: {
    __resolveType: (obj) => {
      if (obj.userType == "customer") {
        return "Customer";
      } else if (obj.userType == "admin") {
        return "Admin";
      } else if (obj.userType == "gardener") {
        return "Gardener";
      } else {
        throw new Error("User type not found");
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Can you please help me out or point out my mistake. Thanks

Comment: The `__resolveType` function must be defined for your GraphQL union type and that is `UserDetails` in that case (note the captial `U`)

Comment: @NilsHartmann It's giving me an error when changing to captial U in UserResolver file.
Error: User.UserDetails defined in resolvers, but not in schema.
I guess the resolver is written for the field inside the type User that is userDetails rather than the union UserDetails

Comment: I think you must register an own resolver for "UserDetails" (type) at root level. In your example you implemented a Resolver for the 'userDetails' field for the `User` type, what is correct if you want to implement the resolver logic for single fields on the `User` type. But to make the union work you need the `__resolveType` on the `UserDetails` type. I think your (root) resolver map should look like this: `resolvers = { Query: { ... }, UserDetails: { __resolveType: ... } }`. hope that helps!

Comment: @NilsHartmann Thanks man, appreciate it, It worked. It was exactly as you pointed out. I declared it in the root, and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.